# Android: AdMob key in Google Code

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an Android app which uses AdMob. I would like to publish this app's source code on code.google.com.

The code contains my AdMob key. If I publish this key to the public, would this post any danger or risk to me of some kind? The documentation I have checked do not seem to mention this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The AdMob publisher ID isn't secret information.  The only thing anybody could do with your publisher ID is use it, but that would just generate you more money!  However, you should recommend that others go and get their own publisher ID.